# designing web app using nodeJS and HighStocks (or Google Annotation Time Line)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-visualization, highcharts

hi im new to nodeJS but i'm interested in making a browser-based app that is able to plot graphs using HighStocks API or Google Annotation Time Line).

how do i tie both nodeJS and API together, are there blogs for this? It is quite hard to find how nodeJS is being used with HighStocks API, or with Annotation Time Line. Any help or directions to blogs with code explained will be really helpful!

hopefully most of the work is done using javascript.

**EDIT**: also do i need to use Dojo if i'm already calling HighStocks API or Google API?

**EDIT 1**: this is for personal use, and to improve skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nodeJS is for server-side development. How you piece the other API's together with nodeJS is up to you, and I don't really know what those API's do so it's hard to say. It looks like they are for data visualization, if so you would likely use them client-side code that runs on  the browser, not in node.

Typically with node you are writing web services; i.e. handling http requests. You could simply use it to make a restful-like service to grab data, for instance example.com/application/getStocks?user=bob which might return some xml or json data. If you wanted, you could use node to serve your entire website, such that example.com/somepage maps to a function in node that returns an HTML page.. i've never done that, but i'm confident it's possible.

Anyway, a typical architecture might be

```
--webserver(e.g. apache): serves up pages w/ HTML & client-side javascript)
--NodeJS : handles specific HTTP requests and serves back repsonses (likely as xml or JSON)
--Browser : where the client side javascript code executes, to consume webservices and API's
```

THe process:

```
1. User enters URL to a page in browser; page is served up by web server
2. javascript in page makes XHR request to a webservice url
3. the url maps to a function in node.
4. node returns response data (probably xml or json)
5. client js in page handles the response data (via callback function)
6. client code calls 3rd party API (again via XHR), passing along pertinent values from the node response data
7. API gives back something fancy
```

Of course, it is entirely possible to call these 3rd party api's from node, and send their result back as its response - whether that makes sense depends on the application and what the API's actually do - judgement call on your part.

Comment: well im working with Yahoo Finance API that grabs stock data (server-side code likely), and the Google/HighStocks are all client-side APIs. because i also want to upload data from excel spreadsheets (or csv), the application is just a personal stock and portfolio monitoring tool that i compare against external excel data